# Dataflow Splittable ReadFn not using multiple workers

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a particularly simple Dataflow pipeline where I want to read a file and output its parsed records to Avro. This works in most cases, except where the source file is particularly large (20+ GB) which causes me to OOM even with particularly large memory machines. I am pretty sure this happens because the non-splittable source is read in its entirety by Beam, so I implemented a splittable DoFn<FileIO.ReadableFile, GenericRecord>

This *functionally* works in that the pipeline now succeeds, which seems to validate my assumption that the single large batch from a non-splittable file is the cause. However, this does not seem to spread the work across multiple workers. I tried the following:

1. Disabled autoscaling (autoscalingAlgorithm=NONE) and set numWorkers to 10. This had the same throughput as numWorkers 1
2. Left autoscaling on with a high maxWorkers. This went briefly up to 2, and then came back down to 1
3. Added a shuffle (Reshuffle.viaRandomKey) after the DoFn, but before the Avro write

Any ideas? The exact code is difficult to share because of company policy, but overall is pretty simple. I implemented the following:

```java
public class SplittableReadFn extends DoFn<FileIO.ReadableFile, GenericRecord> {
// ...
@ProcessElement
public void process(final ProcessContext c, final OffsetRangeTracker tracker) {
   final FileIO.ReadableFile file = c.element();
   // Followed by something like
   ReadableByteStream in = file.open()
   in.seek(tracker.from())
   Parser parser = new Parser(in)
   while (parser.next()) {
     if (parser.getOffset() > tracker.to()) {
        break
     }
     tracker.tryClaim(parser.getOffset())
     c.output(parser.item())
   }
   tracker.markDone()
}

@GetInitialRestriction
public OffsetRange getInitialRestriction(final FileIO.ReadableFile file) {
   return new Offset(0, getSize(file) - 1);
}

@SplitRestriction
public void splitRestriction(final FileIO.ReadableFile file, final OffsetRange restriction, final DoFn.OutputReceiver<OffsetRange> receiver) {
    // chunkRange for test purposes just breaks into at most 500MB chunks
    for (final OffsetRange chunk: chunkRange(restriction)) {
       receiver.output(chunk);
    }
}
```

Comment: re-run the job using the flag --dumpHeapOnOOM and --saveHeapDumpsToGcsPath=gs://<path_to_a_gcs_bucket> this will provide better visibility on what is happening.

Comment: The code looks OK to me. What is the problem you are trying to solve? Improve end-to-end batch pipeline runtime via parallelism across workers? What is the current runtime? Can you share more about the data?

Comment: It turned out that SplittableReadFn isn't distributed to multiple workers. I worked around this by wrapping this in another transform that does a Reshuffle.viaRandomKey() to force its distribution.

Perhaps this was fixed in a later version of Beam in the past year - I've not checked. It sure was a surprise that splittable DoFn didn't support concurrent execution when it was released.

Comment: @GeorgeHilios could you elaborate on your solution? I wrote a set of transformations to read possibly growing number of pubsub topics and store their data in BigQuery and it also "functionally works" but doesn't scale at all. I tried  `.apply(MyPTransformWithSplittableDoFnInside()).apply(Reshuffle.viaRandomKey())` but this doesn't seem to help.